# Python writing a range loop with multiple rows

Tags: python

I'm trying write a script to increment the second column of several rows based on
a range in loop i.e. `nums = range(17501, 17570)`. So on each increment the all values in the second column will `increment to 17202 and then 17203` etc leaving the rest intact , any suggestions?

The data is already in a file so I need some form of `read` and then `write` the ouput, is this even possible ?

```
x1E 17201   18  0   1   0   0   1
x2E 17201   19  0   1   0   0   1
x3E 17201   20  0   1   0   0   1
x4E 17201   21  0   1   0   0   1
x5E 17201   22  0   1   0   0   1
x6X 17201   23  0   1   0   0   1
x7X 17201   24  0   1   0   0   1
x8X 17201   25  0   1   0   0   1
x9X 17201   26  0   1   0   0   1
10X 17201   27  0   1   0   0   1
11X 17201   28  0   1   0   0   1
12X 17201   29  0   1   0   0   1
13X 17201   30  0   1   0   0   1
14X 17201   31  0   1   0   0   1
15X 17201   32  0   1   0   0   1
16X 17201   33  0   1   0   0   1
20X 17201   34  0   1   0   0   1
17X 17201   35  0   1   0   0   1
18X 17201   36  0   1   0   0   1
19X 17201   37  0   1   0   0   1
```

Thanks to ROCKLY LI I got this to work. Only problem it needs sorting as above perhaps by the 3 rd column numerically , how to sort the written output in the file ?

```
nums = range(17201,17920)

with open('Orig.txt', 'r') as fin:
     with open('PLF.txt', 'w') as fout:
         for line in fin.readlines():
             line = line.split()

             #if 17200 < int(line[1]) < 17920:

             #print(line)
             for i in range(0, len(nums),):
                 line[1] = int(line[1]) + 1
                  #line.append(str(line[1] + 1))
                 line = [str(e) for e in line] # Fix type
                 print(line)
                 #fout.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
                 fout.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: you say column, but in what way is this represented? a csv?

Comment: why do you want loop?`df['second']=range(17501,17570)`??

Comment: Hi it will be in a text file ,

Comment: Show us your faulty code and we might be able to help. SO does not code for you, we just help you fix it - maybe.

Comment: nums = range(17501, 17570)
 f = open ('test.txt' , 'w')
  
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(nums),):
        
        
        f.write( " " + str(nums[i]) + "\n")

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of editing the file in place, it's more reasonable to generate a new one and keep the old one, and it's incredibly easy with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('your_file.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
df[1] = df.apply(lambda x: x[1] + 1 if 17501 <= x[1] < 17570 else x[1])
df.to_csv('new_file.txt', sep=' ')
```

And that's it.

Without pandas, you can do:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as fin:
     with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fout:
          for line in fin.readlines():
              line = line.split()
              if 17000 < int(line[1]) < 18000:
                  line[1] = int(line[1]) + 1
              line = [str(e) for e in line] # Fix type
              fout.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: Very interesting , but I can't import pandas 'no module named pandas' error. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Use `pip install pandas`

Comment: Won't let me install (Admin issues) surely there is a basic (i.e. no need for imports) solution

Comment: you got it. I got lazy with the numbers - check for yourself.

Comment: Keep getting this error despite the file being present "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testplfer.txt' "

Comment: @user2262031 you'll need to pass in the relative/absolute path to the file. And I can't help you with that.

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: Fixed. it's a comparison issue adding int(line[1]) can solve.

Comment: I get this now typeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. Should it be in the 'if' line or incremental line or both ?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, are you doing exactly what I have up there? did you include `line = [str(e) for e in line]`?

Comment: Thanks works now but not as expected. I was hoping it would not overwrite the original but add the same lines but with the second column value incremented from 17201 to 17202 (i.e up to 17500 etc) and so on. Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: Just change `line[1] = int(line[1]) + 1)` to `line.append(int(line[1] + 1)` within that `if` block. You'll have your column as the last column.

Comment: Thanks , didn't make any difference. It still only updates the first 20 lines. What I hoped for was these first 20 lines (should be variable) are reproduced with only the second column changing. This could be reproduced many times based on the 2nd column range i.e. 17201 to 17300